# Get page access token with Facebook API 5.0 PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need to post messages on a Facebook page. Specifically I want to post via `cron`.

Here's what the API docs say:

> Page Access Token – These access tokens are similar to user access tokens, except that they provide permission to APIs that read, write or modify the data belonging to a Facebook Page. To obtain a page access token you need to start by obtaining a user access token and asking for the manage_pages permission. Once you have the user access token you then get the page access token via the Graph API.

How I can obtain a user access and page access token without a page callback? Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to do it from cron, or PHP?

Comment: @NateBarbettini  even with cron it can be PHP, this is not excluding each other ... ?

Comment: @AxelAmthor Fair enough, I forgot about that.

Comment: Exactly, it's not a Linux CRON but a planned task in a PHP program. But like NateBarbettini say we can do a CRON with a PHP script so it is the same thing in my case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you need it an Extended Page Token, it is valid forever. You get one like this:

- Authorize with the `manage_pages` permission (and `publish_pages` if you want to post as Page later), to get a User Token
- Extend the User Token
- Use `/me/accounts?fields=access_token` with the Extended User Token to get a list of all your Pages with Extended Page Tokens - or use `/page-id?fields=access_token` to get an Extended Page Token for a specific Page

Information about all Tokens and how to extend the User Token:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 7):

PHP API V5

The below code worked for me after 24 hours of head scratching .... hope this helps by the way if you need this code to work you should have completed the first two steps

1. Should have login to facebook I used `getRedirectLoginHelper`
2. Set session variable with the received user access token on the call back file `$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;`

---

```
$fbApp  = new Facebook\FacebookApp( 'xxx', 'xxx', 'v2.7' );
$fb      = new Facebook\Facebook( array(
    'app_id' => 'xxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7'
) );
$requestxx = new FacebookRequest(
    $fbApp,
    $_SESSION['fb_access_token'],//my user access token
    'GET',
    '/{page-id}?fields=access_token',
    array( 'ADMINISTER' )
);
$responset  = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest( $requestxx );
$json           = json_decode( $responset->getBody() );
$page_access    = $json->access_token;

//posting to page   
$requesty = new FacebookRequest(
    $fbApp,
    $page_access ,
    'POST',
    '/{page-id}/feed?message=Hello fans YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'
);
$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest( $requesty );
var_dump( $response );
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: Please understand I checked using a php file not inside a wp-plugin, This worked for me back in 2016, and another person on 2017 feb, therefore instead of copy pasting code please check the docs and compare your code !

Answer (score 5):

You can get the page token this way:

```
$response = $fb->get('/'.$pageId.'?fields=access_token', (string)$accessToken);
$json = json_decode($response->getBody());
$page_token = $json->access_token;
$response = $fb->post('/'.$pageId.'/feed', $fbData, $page_token);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only JavaScript code, but once you have an access token, you may get the pages which can be adminstered by the given user. This will contain a page access token for each of them:

```
jQuery.ajax({type: "GET",
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/accounts?access_token=" + userToken,
                async: false,
                data: jsonRequest,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
```

The data given back is like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "access_token": "CAACni8TcBB0B...cZBJfwZDZD",
      "category": "Computers/Technology",
      "name": "abc",
      "id": "...",
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER",
        "EDIT_PROFILE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MODERATE_CONTENT",
        "CREATE_ADS",
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    },
    {
      "access_token": "CAA...ZDZD",
      "category": "App Page",
      "name": "xyz",
      "id": "....",
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER",
        "EDIT_PROFILE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MODERATE_CONTENT",
        "CREATE_ADS",
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

`access_token` is your page token. You may transform the above request into PHP easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.
I understand how i can get the page access token.
But how can i get the user token ?

Comment: Think i find :
1) Get an access Token from : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
2) Get a long live access token from https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=&client_secret=&fb_exchange_token=
3) Get a permanent access token with your precedent link