# Graph API error #200 even with correct permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm setting up a bot to auto-post on a facebook page. But when i run the script, the graph API throws the following error:

> Graph returned an error: (#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

but in the app's permissions, both `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` are marked as allowed, as well as the user (who is also the owner of the page) is setup as app admin.

i know this is (or, at least, *was*) a know issue but i've found no answer whatsoever.

is there any way to solve/work arround it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Make sure you actually authorize the User with those permissions, debug the Token in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/
- Use a Page Token of that Page, not a User Token: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32924419/7335057

Comment: The permissions were already set, but i wasn't using a page token (actually i didn't even know they existed lol). Thanks!

Comment: hwo to get page token to post in group, I am having page token for page not for groups

Comment: Absolutely great answer! Worked great for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876100/get-page-access-token-with-facebook-api-5-0-php/39322956 To find out how to get a page access token.

Comment: "Use a Page Token of that Page, not a User Token" is important!!`

Answer (score 0):

Enable two factor authentication (mobile otp based) in your accounts .. then it will work fine